# React Router focus on route change not documented or missing

Tags: react-router, accessibility, single-page-application, reach-router

Per [this React Router announcement](https://reacttraining.com/blog/reach-react-router-future/), React Router and Reach Router are now the same project (more or less). [The Reach Router docs](https://reach.tech/router/) says

> Router manages the focus of your app on route transitions. There’s nothing you have to do about it, it just happens.

At present there's nothing in the [React Router Web API docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/) about focus (I did a text search) and the [roadmap](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6885) has

> Add focus management APIs

in the backlog.

Is this feature still coming or are we waiting for [this React RFC](https://github.com/devongovett/rfcs-1/blob/patch-1/text/2019-focus-management.md) or is it there and not documented? Asking because it's been a while since the announcement and it's understandable if there are documentation gaps. Want to make sure it's really not there before I keep rolling my own.

Comment: it's not there, the two main/only? maintainers of react-router have been busy with their new project (remix) which is why react-router v6 has been in beta for a more than a year